# Get city polygon from name

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python. I have the name of the city/postal address and I wish to find out the coordinates of a polygon around it. I did read about it at a lot of places but couldn't get the concrete guidance.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import pprint

base_url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?"

address=input("Enter location: ")

main_url=base_url + urlencode({"address":address})

r=requests.get(main_url)

json_obj=r.json()

if 'status' not in json_obj or json_obj["status"]!="OK":
    print("fail")
    print(json_obj)


lat=json_obj["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
lng=json_obj["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
print("Latitudes:" ,lat)
print("Longitudes:", lng)
location=json_obj["results"][0]["formatted_address"]
print("Location:", location).
```

This code used to give me the location lat long, on entering the location name, but it doesn't work! Plus, **I want to fetch the polygon from the city name** and not the location.
I also found this website. http://overpass-turbo.eu/ where I can enter the city name and download the polygon coordinates but I do not wish to do this manually every time. If I have 100 cities, I do not want to enter them one by one and download geoson documents for all of them and then re-use them in my python queries. Is there some API, some better way of doing it?

**EDIT:** This is the format of the export.

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "generator": "overpass-turbo",
  "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.",
  "timestamp": "2016-07-14T03:50:02Z",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "id": "relation/127864",
      "properties": {
        "@id": "relation/127864",
        "admin_level": "6",
        "alt_name": "Soton",
        "borough": "yes",
        "boundary": "administrative",
        "designation": "unitary_authority",
        "name": "Southampton",
        "name:ja": "サウサンプトン",
        "name:ru": "Саутгемптон",
        "name:sr": "Саутемптон",
        "ons_code": "00MS",
        "operator": "Southampton City Council",
        "place": "city",
        "population": "228600",
        "ref:gss": "E06000045",
        "ref:lau:1": "UKJ3200",
        "ref:nuts:3": "UKJ32",
        "source:ons_code": "OS_OpenData_CodePoint Codelist.txt",
        "source:ref:gss": "ONS_OpenData",
        "source:ref:lau:1": "ONS_OpenData",
        "source:ref:nuts:3": "ONS_OpenData",
        "type": "boundary",
        "website": "http://www.southampton.gov.uk/",
        "wikipedia": "en:Southampton",
        "@geometry": "bounds"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -1.479005,
              50.8715095
            ],
            [
              -1.3219862,
              50.8715095
            ],
            [
              -1.3219862,
              50.9561307
            ],
            [
              -1.479005,
              50.9561307
            ],
            [
              -1.479005,
              50.8715095
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The geometry.coordinates is what I'm looking for!

Comment: "*This code used to give me the location, but not anymore!*" - if this is what you are asking about, you need to explain what it should do, and what it does - errors, wrong output, etc. "*Is there some API*" - if this is your question, product recommendations or external resource requests are off-topic. "*Is there some better way of doing it?*" - if this is your question, you need to define what "better" means to you, and what else you've tried. "*This is the format of the export.*" - if processing this is your question, you should really have your attempted code so far... be more specific...

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The part in bold is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what your question is. But given your export, you can get the coordinates out of it with:

```
export = """{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  [..]
  }"""

import json
results = json.loads(export)
print results['features'][0]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
```

Try it online: https://repl.it/CbtH/0

Comment: This code works. I'd tried this already. My point wasI have a lot of cities. My question was, not to export this everytime from the website for every city. Is there a more automatic, API based way of doing this.